# Filtering data points for signal processing

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

I'm trying to make a low pass filter using MatLab to filter a matrix of data points I've imported.
My question is, although I'm already able to filter a made up noise by filter functions, I don't know how to filter a matrix of data points. the noisy signal and filtered signal, as I expect, can be seen in the upper figure and lower figure respectively.

please help me out.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Probably, the threshold of your lowpass filter is very low. Anyway, you should post your code so that we can find what's causing the unexpected result.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean by filtering a matrix. Do you want to filter it as an image or are we speaking about filtering multiple time series which are collected in the matrix? As it was already mentioned you should add your code here.